# Android execute native library from Runtime.exec() or Java.Process()

Tags: java, android, c++, c, java-native-interface

with the latest `Android Q` it harder or in some cases impossible to `execute native executables` in `/data/data/com.example/files/example.so`

For example i am executing the C/C++ executables with : 
`Process.exec("/data/data/com.example/files/example.so -a -e -n 192.168.1.1")`
and getting its output from `InputStreamReader(process.inputStream)`.

I am just wondering if there is a way to load the library from Java Native e.x :

`System.loadlibrary("example")` and after that send the same `command` as above and getting the `output` directly from it ?

Thanks

> P.s : A example would be great if this is possible !

https://repl.it/repls/CookedLoyalProfiles

How to convert something like passing this : `"executable -a -e -n"` to `JNI call` and `read the output`

Comment: @Onik, thanks for your comment. I understand how to build an executable, but i don't know how to convert something like "executable -a -e -n" to JNI call and read the output

Comment: `.so` files are not normally *executable*, but *loadable*.

Comment: @DavisHerring, i know that but to include them on APK file should add `lib` and `.so` in the end

Comment: OK—I just wanted to make sure which action you were trying to take with it.

Comment: I am surprised your executable is under **files**. If you name it *correctly*, as **lib*exectutable*.so**, you will find it automatically unpacked fro you under **lib**, and you can run it with `Process.exec()` from there.

Answer (score 0):

rename your `exectuable` file to `libexectutable.so` put it into your project `app/src/main/jniLibs/arm64-v8a` folder.

```java
File workdir = new File(getApplicationInfo().nativeLibraryDir);
Process process = new ProcessBuilder("./libexectutable.so", "-some-args").directory(workdir).start();
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
// maybe a while loop
in.readLine(); // represent one line output of the process
```